# how to Host Angularjs app or M.E.A.N. client side app on a Apache or a NodeJS server?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, apache, host, mean-stack

I just developed a basic CRUD functioning MEAN stack app. I hosted the server side api i.e. build in **nodejs**.

- But, I'm finding difficulty in **hosting** the client side UI. It is build with **angularjs** has bower components and grunt serve. Both are running perfect in my client side.

  - Can any one suggest where and how can i **host the client side**?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where you mean what hosting provider?

Comment: Can you not just use Nginx to send the client side code to the browser?

Comment: You can host the client side app in node too. If you've got express or something running you can add static routes alongside your api routes and just serve the whole thing.

Comment: I tried hosting on godaddy apache server it didn't work that was quite obvious.

Comment: @shaunakde Tried hosting the app on node server same place where my node api the server side is hosted. But as we know angularjs doesnt have any index.js/server.js file I mean a index js file like in nodejs . so the server threw error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For guys still struggling and having same problem figuring out how to host and Grunt Angularjs app on node servers or apache servers. Here are the options:

1. Use `Grunt Build` cmd inside your angularjs app it will build a **dist** folder that has all the minified files to launch your app. Upload this files into your **Apache server** and you are good to go.
2. If you want to host it on a **NodeJS server** follow steps in this [Video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bxwCbyoyKgI&list=FLgSOcWdcAoXfOr1fvYqJq1Q&index=1)